# Java, Sorting lists different type by date

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have three lists `List<A> a;`,`List<B> b;` and `List<C> c;`.
The types A,B and C have date attributes.
How i can order the three list by date and print all of the items by date, Like this example

```
        List<A> a = new ArrayList<A>();
        a.add(new A("1", "22/04/2017", "", ""));
        a.add(new A("2", "25/04/2017", "", ""));
        a.add(new A("3", "30/04/2017", "", ""));
        a.add(new A("4", "01/04/2017", "", ""));


        List<B> b = new ArrayList<B>();
        b.add(new B("5", "23/04/2017", "", ""));
        b.add(new B("6", "05/04/2017", "", ""));

        List<C> c = new ArrayList<C>();
        c.add(new C("7", "26/04/2017", "", ""));
        c.add(new C("8", "02/04/2017", "", ""));
```

output is:

```
        4   01/04/2017  --> A
        8   02/04/2017  --> C
        6   05/04/2017  --> B
        1   22/04/2017  --> A
        5   23/04/2017  --> B
        2   25/04/2017  --> A
        7   26/04/2017  --> C
        3   30/04/2017  --> A
```

Comment: Can you better explain the requirement to sort three collections of different types?  Are the `A`, `B` and `C` classes somehow related?

Comment: There is no relation between the classes, only creating date attribute is mutual.

Comment: Can you create a common interface for all three classes?

Comment: No this types are exists, i can not change this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8

If i can understand your Class design look like this :

**Class A**

```
class A {

    String s1;
    String s2;
    String s3;
    String s4;

    public A(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
        this.s3 = s3;
        this.s4 = s4;
    }
    //..getters and setter
}
```

**Class B**

```
class B extends A {

    public B(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {
        super(s1, s2, s3, s4);
    }

}
```

**Class C**

```
class C extends A {

    public C(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {
        super(s1, s2, s3, s4);
    }
}
```

In this case you can use :

```
//Create a List, and add all the a, b, c List to this list
List<A> k = new ArrayList<>();
k.addAll(a);
k.addAll(b);
k.addAll(c);
```

then you can sort this List using a `Comparator` like this

```
Collections.sort(k, new Comparator<A>() {
    public int compare(A p1, A p2) {
        return p1.getS2().compareTo(p2.getS2());
    }
});
```

Print your List

```
k.forEach((v) -> System.out.println(v.getS2()));
```

---

**EDIT**

**Solution 2**

In case there are no relation between your Class then you can use :

```
List<String> k = new ArrayList<>();
a.forEach((v)-> k.add(v.s2));
b.forEach((v)-> k.add(v.s2));
c.forEach((v)-> k.add(v.s2));

Collections.sort(k, String::compareTo);

k.forEach((v) -> System.out.println(v));
```

---

**Solution 3**

If you want to go far, you can :

1. Create a common class (CommonClass) which take the common attributes between the Three classes
2. Create a List of this type (CommonClass)
3. Loop throw this 3 Lists and create new Objects of CommonClass and add them to the new List
4. Then Sort this final List

Or :

**Solution 4**

You can create a `List<List<String>>` like this :

```
List<List<String>> k = new ArrayList<>();
a.forEach((v) -> k.add(Arrays.asList(v.s1, v.s2, v.s3, v.s4)));
b.forEach((v) -> k.add(Arrays.asList(v.s1, v.s2, v.s3, v.s4)));
b.forEach((v) -> k.add(Arrays.asList(v.s1, v.s2, v.s3, v.s4)));


Collections.sort(k, (o1, o2) -> {
    return o1.get(1).compareTo(o2.get(1));
});

k.forEach((v) -> System.out.println(v.get(0) + "____" + v.get(1)));
```

Comment: There is no relation between the classes.

Comment: Ops, i am using java 7 not 8, sorry can not try this

Comment: check the new Solutions @KaramJabareen you can take the idea and use Java 7 it is not hard

Answer (score 2):

You could create a stream of all the items and sort it using a custom comparator:

```
Stream.of(a, b, c).flatMap(List::stream)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> {
            if (o instanceof A) return ((A) o).date;
            if (o instanceof B) return ((B) o).date;
            if (o instanceof C) return ((C) o).date;
            throw new RuntimeException("illegal type");
        }))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you want to order three lists of different types you are really saying that you want to create a single collection and sort it. That means (for Java at least) that the items need to have a common type.

Once they are in a common collection there needs to be a common set of things you can do to the items. In the example you've given in the question the only thing they can do is be converted to a string, though I expect you'll eventually need to be able to do other things to them.

So I suggest you create an interface that contains the methods you want to perform on the sorted list and then add objects of that type into the list:

```
public interface ABC {
    Date getDate();
}

List<ABC> abcList;
```

Adding an `A` to that list would look like this:

```
abcList.add(a::getDate);
```

Similarly for `B` and `C`.

Now sorting and printing the list is pretty trivial:

```
abcList.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ABC::getDate))
    .map(ABC::toString)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: There is no point in placing `toString()` method in interface since this method is already part of Object API and its implementation will be inherited at some point (so you can't even enforce anyone to re-implement it)

Comment: Good point. I'll remove that. Makes it a functional interface as well which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

If your classes aren't related at all there is no other way than to assemble first all A, B and C into one of type Object:

```
List<Object>
```

Then sort it providing a Comparator which extracts all the needed values the hard way (using if..else cascades with instanceof).

If at least the getter methods of the different classes would have the same name (e.g. getId() for the first string, getDate() for the second string, etc.) you can avoid the instanceof if..else by using introspection.